# li border doesn't keep around element

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to build a menu without sucess.
I'm trying to set a border to all my li elements, but the border has kept on bottom. How can I turn the border all around my li element?

take a look at my code: http://jsfiddle.net/KByqr/

Comment: Something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/KByqr/1/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Remove the `-bottom` from these two lines:

```
border-bottom-style: solid;
border-bottom-width: medium;
```

#### Make them:

```
border-style: solid;
border-width: medium;
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KByqr/2/

Answer (score 3):

Set a `border-width`.  A `border-width`, `border-color`, and `border-style` are necessary.  ie: `border:1px solid black;`